# how to define a selector in swift3 for an override method

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I want to define a selector in CBPeripheralDelegate, which is `func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?)`.

In swift3, it is renamed to `peripheral(_: didUpdateValueFor:error)`, and it is same as the `func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForDescriptor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: NSError?)`

So when I try to define a selector like this `#selector(CBPeripheralDelegate.peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:))` will cause a compile error: `ambiguous use`.

And I try to define like the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35#Selectors) describe: `#selector(((CBPeripheralDelegate.peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:)) as (CBPeripheralDelegate) -> (CBPeripheral, CBCharacteristic, NSError) -> Void)`, 
failed either.

So what is the right way to define a selector in swift3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this may be a flaw in the current `#selector` notation and you should send a bug report to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) or [swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/). (Or I may be just missing something...)

To work this around, define a class conforming to the protocol, and define the method that you want to make a selector for.

```
class TheClass: NSObject, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        //No need to actually implement the method
    }
}
```

And use that class name in your `#selector()`:

```
#selector(TheClass.peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:))
```

You may already have a class implementing the method, then you can use the class name of it.

Objective-C selectors does not keep a class name information, so, the selector can be used for any classes which may be implementing the method.

If you want to make a selector from inside a class which conforms the protocol and has a definition for the method, you can write it as:

```
#selector(peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:))
```