# Ambiguous use of 'connection(_:didReceive:)'

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurlconnectiondelegate, xcode8

```
static let didReceiveResponseSelector : Selector = #selector((NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.connection(_:didReceive:)) as (NSURLConnectionDataDelegate) ->(NSURLConnection,URLResponse) -> ())
```

This code is returning error:

> Ambiguous use of 'connection(_:didReceive:)'

I referred to the official evolution thread of Apple on GitHub, I respected the syntax but is not working:

[Referencing the Objective-C selector of a method](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md#user-content-detailed-design)

Comment: Unfortunately, disambiguating with `as` casting does not work for methods declared in protocols. Please check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39221563/6541007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, just add "?":

```
    static let didReceiveResponseSelector : Selector = #selector((NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.connection(_:didReceive:)) as ((NSURLConnectionDataDelegate) -> (NSURLConnection,URLResponse) -> void)?)
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` is a protocol, you can't create a Selector using `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.connection(_:didReceive:)`, you must used an implementation of NSURLConnectionDataDelegate like :

```
class YourDelegateImplementation: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
     public func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive data: Data) {
     }
}
```

And then you can create a Selector like this :

```
let yourDelegate: YourDelegateImplementation = YourDelegateImplementation()
let yourSelector : Selector = #selector(yourDelegate.connection(_:didReceive:))
```

Comment: no it's possible for other delegate so it have to be possible for this one too, and your code not work

Comment: look at this
#selector(NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.connectionDidFinishLoading(_:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast the Selector:

```
let didReceiveResponseSelector = #selector(NSURLConnectionDelegate.connection(_:didReceive:))
```

It's also worth noting that the delegate function `connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge)` has been deprecated in favor of `connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestFor challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge)`.

Comment: sorry I need the selector for didReceive data: Data

Comment: you are confusing between NSURLConnectionDataDelegate and NSURLConnectionDelegate